# The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp, async-await, visual-studio-2017

Здравствуйте, проблема заключается в следующем: при написании кода, с использованием **await**, к примеру

```
    StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFolder folder = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("FirstLessonQuestions");
```

компилятор ругается и выдает следующие ошибки
[image: получаемые ошибки]

Пробовал переустанавливать VS, качать SDK для Windows и т.д - ничего не помогает. Использую VS Community 2017. Проект пишется под UWP.

Comment: А если создать чистый проект uwp и попробовать использовать `await`?

Comment: Пробовал, на других проектах аналогичная проблема.

Comment: А под какой .NET Framework ваш проект? У меня приложение по умолчанию под UWP работает без вопросов.

Comment: @VlaD Я пробовал различные версии фрейморка - результат один. Насколько я понимаю, компилятор отказывается находить ссылку на Windows.Runtime , хотя при добавлении соответствующей dll появляется сообщение о том, что данная ссылка подключена по умолчанию.

Comment: @Алексей: Чрезвычайно странно. Попробуйте на другом компьютере сделать то же самое.

Comment: @VlaD Пробовал, на других все работает. Через пару недель попробую переустановить Windows, мб. это поможет.

Comment: @Алексей: Стойте :) А если создать проект на другой машине, а потом принести на эту — работает?

Comment: У вас, судя по всему, криво стоит .NET. Вы ничего не меняли в системе вручную?

Comment: @VlaD Во вторник попробую и сообщу о результате) 
Когда появилась эта проблема - сразу пошел искать в гугле способ ее решения. И в одном предлагалось вручную удалить все пакеты SDK и VS, а затем переустановить их.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить ```using System;``` на страницу  с ошибкой.

Comment: @MakeMakeluv уже добавлено по умолчанию