# Хранение введённых пользователем данных

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, хранение-данных

Здравствуйте, вопрос заключается в следующем:
как можно сохранять данные, введенные пользователем, не используя БД или их запись в файл? При серфинге в интернете натолкнулся на

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer
```

но так и не разобрался в работе данного класса. Выслушаю любые предложения по данной теме и буду особенно благодарен за помощь в разборе вышеизложенного класса, спасибо.

Comment: Любая запись в конечном итоге запись в файл. Вы думаете, база данных где хранит их? В файле. (Или в сырой партиции, такое тоже бывает.) Ну или если не запись в файл, то передача по сети, с записью в файл на другом компьютере.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, подчерпнул для себя немного нового. Но все же хотелось бы побольше узнать о приведенном мной классе, если Вас это сильно не затруднит. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, это класс для UWP-приложений. Для них инфраструктура Windows Store предоставляет изолированное от других приложений хранилище данных. Где именно — наверное, тоже в файле, но для Windows Store-приложений этот файл всё равно недоступен. Для десктопных приложений этот класс, как я понимаю, недоступен.

Comment: Т.к. это класс, то верно ли я понимаю, что я могу передавать его значения по фрейму между страницами? Т.е. если у меня, к примеру, есть окно регистрации пользователя и введённые им данные я сохраню в объект данного класса, то смогу ли я пользоваться ими на других страницах моего UWP-приложения?

Comment: Исходя из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer#Examples), вам не нужно создавать свой экземпляр, у вас и так есть один глобальный экземпляр. (Я сам не знаю, никогда не писал UWP-приложений.)

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время, буду разбираться)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что наше обсуждение поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox"/>
    <Button Name="button" Content="Save me" Click="button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

в обработчике клика по кнопке:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["key"] = textBox.Text;
}
```

В конструкторе страницы:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    if (settings.Values.ContainsKey("key"))
        textBox.Text = (string)settings.Values["key"];
}
```

<sub>[Чуть больше информации в статье на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151467/) (да, она актуальна для UWP)</sub>

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, обязательно прочитаю прикреплённую Вами статью. Насколько я понимаю, эти данные будут глобальными для всего приложения и доступ к ним я могу получить из любой страницы, верно?

Comment: Да, конечно, но если вам хранилище это нужно только для того чтобы передавать данные между страницами в одной сессии, то сохранение в постоянное хранилище - плохое решение.

Comment: Может быть я неправильно понял Ваш ответ, но нет, идея все же состоит в регистрации пользователя и хранении этих данных постоянно. Была идея использовать запись в файл, но с недавних пор VS упорно отказывается работать с async/await операциями, поэтому выбор пал именно на постоянное хранилище.

Comment: В таком случае используйте этот ответ

Comment: @Алексей: Visual Studio не работает с async/await? о_О А почему я этого не заметил?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753621/the-type-iasyncaction-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced 
Буду очень благодарен Вам, если поможете.

Comment: @VladD, комментарий выше был адресован вам, я так понимаю ;)

Comment: @Алексей, используйте обращение по @, иначе адресат не получит уведомления о комментарии и не вспомнит что ему надо зайти в топик